# How can I test my own application in ipod touch and iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ipod-touch

I have some iphone application that I created. I want to test my application in ipod touch.  How can I test my application in ipod touch? Now I have no Apple id my own. If I open an id then how many applications can be tested with that id?

If you have an available solution then please give me the answer and help me.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to test iPhone applications on a device, you'll need to be apply for the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/apply.html). It costs $99 and will also let you submit applications to the App Store.

Comment: The number of apps that you can then upload to your phone and submit to the app store is unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are accepted, you can develop an unlimited number of applications (and submit them to the App Store) with your one identity.

Answer (score 0):

Get an apple id and download the dev kit. It has all you need, including an emulator and a method for installing on local devices.